# How to copy file (as in file handle, not contents) to clipboard from within SlickEdit or Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, clipboard

I'm wondering if there is built-in or plug-in functionality for this feature for either of these apps. I'd like to be looking at file open in SlickEdit or Notepad++, and then either from a menu or right click context menu, copy a file handle (not the name/path of the file or file contents) to the clipboard. So I could then go to Windows Explorer and to a directory and paste the files in there.

Sometimes I don't want to navigate in Explorer to where those files live, and I don't want to do SaveAs since it replaces your working copy with the copied version.

Answer (score 0):

In Notepad++, press <kbd>F5</kbd> (Run command) and enter the following command (only once):

```
explorer /select,$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)
```

followed by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Now you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> for copy and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to close the Explorer window.

This sequence can be automated to single keyboard shortcut e.g. using [AutoHotKey](http://ahkscript.org/).